# Check if package is compatible with .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core

I started programming with .NET Core and ASP.NET Core and after reading many Docs/Tutorials i still am not sure of how to realize if a Nuget-(Meta-)Package is comptabile/usable within my .NET-Core-App.

1. How to check if a NuGet-Package is compatible with .NET Core.
   E.g. the often recited [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Is it compatible/usable - and how to see this?
2. Is there a list of all the available .NET Core packages?

([Like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages) it lists a few

> key NuGet packages for .NET Core

). But since they say those are `"key"` packages i would assume there are more. But which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that will be helpful - lots of popular packages https://github.com/thangchung/awesome-dotnet-core

I also don't see nuget.org mentioned anywhere so:
https://nuget.org

General rule of thumb for me is: 
if package has a dependency on net standard or .net core, it will run with .net core(mind the versions also)

Comment: The first link is not very helpful in the package hunt. NuGet.org might be, but interpreting its information is not obvious. A more convenient option should be FuGet.org, https://www.fuget.org/

Answer (score 3):

The best way to understand compatibility is table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)

In this table you can check what API version support NuGet package. If it is standard 1.0+ - it works with .Net Core

For checking (supported API version) dependencies on your package, you can check page of package on nuget.org or in your package manager

[Here is an example for Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhGdE.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net

Go to site and search for package to find its compatibility

Comment: Good link but doesn't seem to find everything. For example looking for RestSharp doesn't find it but investigating in NuGet there is a RestSharp.NetCore.

Comment: doesn't seem to find any packages for me. shame.

Comment: Same issue. Doesn't find a lot of packages.

Comment: Doesn't find any packages

Comment: This answer probably should be revised to claim that it was correct in 2016. So much has changed in the following years, so it is no longer the right answer to follow.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in fact you don't have to worry, the NET core application will indicate you if the package is compatible or not when you will run a `dotnet restore` command in your project.

Let say that you have the famous CSVHelper package registered in your csproj file :

`<PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="0.12.0"/>`

Then, when you'll run any dotnet command such as `build` or `run`, you'll have the following input in the console in case of, here, cross-compatibility:

```
YourProjet/aspnetapp.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'CsvHelper 0.12.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Basically, it mean that NET Core application can use ASP.NET NuGet package, and so far, I've never cross on a non-compatible package. Even if version is incorrect, the build will get the most recent matching version of the NuGet package.

Hoped it answer your question.